# error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null after adding and deleting an Event

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, event-listener

I have this unfinished tic-tac-toe game and i'm having trouble when i finish the first game, then press "iniciar" to play again. I get this innerHTML error, can't figure out why is this happening and i would really appreciate some help.

It actually works like this:
"Iniciar" to start playing
When game finishes if it's a tie
"Iniciar" again
If there is a winner the scoreboard changes.
"Iniciar" (here is when the error occurs)

"Reiniciar" resets the score and start a new game. This gives an error too.

It's weird because when it's a TIE, there's no problem with #errorenTurno 
But when there's a winner and i start over, the error is there.

```
<html>

<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Peralta' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var turno = 1,
            puntosX = 0,
            puntosCero = 0; // some globals
        window.addEventListener('load', start, false);

        function start() {

            document.getElementById('empezar').addEventListener('click', inicio, false); // yellow buttons
            document.getElementById('reiniciar').addEventListener('click', reinicio, false);
        }

        function reinicio() { // yellow buttons
            document.getElementById('ganX').innerHTML = 0;
            document.getElementById('gandO').innerHTML = 0;
            inicio();
        }


        function inicio() { // adds listener to all spans in the table
            var x;

            for (x = 0; x <= 8; x++) {
                document.getElementById('boton' + x).innerHTML = '';
            }
            for (x = 0; x <= 8; x++) {
                document.getElementById('boton' + x).addEventListener('click', jugada, false);
            }
        }

        function jugada(evt) { // checks the move
            document.getElementById('errorenTurno').innerHTML = '';
            var bloqueJugado = evt.target;
            if (turno === 1) {
                if (bloqueJugado.innerHTML === 'O' || bloqueJugado.innerHTML === 'X') {
                    document.getElementById('errorenTurno').innerHTML = 'Ya se ha jugado aquíx'; // already marked
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (bloqueJugado.innerHTML !== 'X') {
                        evt.target.innerHTML = 'X';
                    }
                }
                verificarGan('X', 1);
                turno = 0;
                return;
            }

            if (turno === 0) {
                if (bloqueJugado.innerHTML === 'X' || bloqueJugado.innerHTML === 'O') {
                    document.getElementById('errorenTurno').innerHTML = 'Ya se ha jugado aquí0'; // already marked
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (bloqueJugado.innerHTML !== 'O') {
                        evt.target.innerHTML = 'O';
                    }
                }
                verificarGan('O', 2);
                turno = 1;
                return;
            }
        }

        function verificarGan(mov, jug) { // verifies if there is a winning move
            var j1 = document.getElementById('boton0');
            var j2 = document.getElementById('boton1');
            var j3 = document.getElementById('boton2');
            var j4 = document.getElementById('boton3');
            var j5 = document.getElementById('boton4');
            var j6 = document.getElementById('boton5');
            var j7 = document.getElementById('boton6');
            var j8 = document.getElementById('boton7');
            var j9 = document.getElementById('boton8');
            var detuvo = 0;

            function detener(gano) { // deletes the event listener from spans in table
                if (gano == 1) {
                    for (x = 0; x <= 8; x++) {
                        document.getElementById('boton' + x).removeEventListener('click', jugada);
                    }
                }
            }

            function puntoTablero() { // adds points to scoreboard, since i added this i started having trouble
                if (jug == 1) {
                    puntosX = puntosX + 1;
                    document.getElementById('ganX').innerHTML = puntosX;
                }
                if (jug == 2) {
                    puntosCero = puntosCero + 1;
                    document.getElementById('gandO').innerHTML = puntosCero;
                }
            }

            // checking all winning moves one by one. Then it applies the needed functions.
            if (j1.innerHTML == mov && j2.innerHTML == mov && j3.innerHTML == mov) {
                document.getElementById('ganador').innerHTML = 'Ha ganado el jugador ' + jug;
                detener(1);
                puntoTablero();
            }
            if (j4.innerHTML == mov && j5.innerHTML == mov && j6.innerHTML == mov) {
                document.getElementById('ganador').innerHTML = 'Ha ganado el jugador ' + jug;
                detener(1);
                puntoTablero();
            }
            if (j7.innerHTML == mov && j8.innerHTML == mov && j9.innerHTML == mov) {
                document.getElementById('ganador').innerHTML = 'Ha ganado el jugador ' + jug;
                detener(1);
                puntoTablero();
            }
            if (j1.innerHTML == mov && j4.innerHTML == mov && j7.innerHTML == mov) {
                document.getElementById('ganador').innerHTML = 'Ha ganado el jugador ' + jug;
                detener(1);
                puntoTablero();
            }
            if (j2.innerHTML == mov && j5.innerHTML == mov && j8.innerHTML == mov) {
                document.getElementById('ganador').innerHTML = 'Ha ganado el jugador ' + jug;
                detener(1);
                puntoTablero();
            }
            if (j3.innerHTML == mov && j6.innerHTML == mov && j9.innerHTML == mov) {
                document.getElementById('ganador').innerHTML = 'Ha ganado el jugador ' + jug;
                detener(1);
                puntoTablero();
            }
            if (j1.innerHTML == mov && j5.innerHTML == mov && j9.innerHTML == mov) {
                document.getElementById('ganador').innerHTML = 'Ha ganado el jugador ' + jug;
                detener(1);
                puntoTablero();
            }
            if (j7.innerHTML == mov && j5.innerHTML == mov && j3.innerHTML == mov) {
                document.getElementById('ganador').innerHTML = 'Ha ganado el jugador ' + jug;
                detener(1);
                puntoTablero();
            }




        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .laVieja {
            font-family: Peralta;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: 100px;
            cursor: default;
            color: black;
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
        .laVieja td {} .laVieja span {
            font-size: 100px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid white;
            width: 160px;
            height: 160px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 150px;
        }
        span {
            clear: both;
        }
        .botonZ {
            font-family: Peralta;
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 18px;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 150px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: lightyellow;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            top: 90px;
            left: 10px;
        }
        .botonZ:hover {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        #reiniciar {} * {
            font-family: Peralta;
        }
        #ganador {
            font-size: 30px;
            border: 1px solid white;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 130px;
            top: 80px;
            display: block;
            color: green;
        }
        #estadisticas {
            width: 350px;
            height: 400px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 100px;
            left: 530px;
            border: 1px solid white;
        }
        #ganadasX {
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        #ganadasO {
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        #ganX {
            font-size: 30px;
            color: green;
        }
        #gandO {
            font-size: 30px;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <table border="1" class="laVieja">
        <tr>
            <td><span id="boton0">1</span>
            </td>
            <td><span id="boton1">2</span>
            </td>
            <td><span id="boton2">3</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="boton3">4</span>
            </td>
            <td><span id="boton4">5</span>
            </td>
            <td><span id="boton5">6</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="boton6">7</span>
            </td>
            <td><span id="boton7">8</span>
            </td>
            <td><span id="boton8">9</span>
            </td>
    </table>
    <div id="estadisticas">

        <p><span id="ganadasX">Ganadas X:&nbsp&nbsp  </span><span id="ganX">10</span>
        </p>
        <p><span id="ganadasO">Ganadas O:&nbsp&nbsp  </span><span id="gandO">5</span>
        </p>
        <p><span id="ganador"><span id="errorenTurno"></span></span>
        </p>
        <div id="empezar" class="botonZ">Iniciar</div>
        <div id="reiniciar" class="botonZ">Reiniciar Juego</div>

    </div>


    </tr>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While checking your inner moves the innerHTML of the div with id `ganador`  is replaced by `Ha ganado el jugador`. SO now what happens is that the span with id `errorenTurno` is lost.

Your `errorenTurno` span is inside the ganador span.

```
<p><span id="ganador"><span id="errorenTurno"></span></span>
```

So either you have to append the message to `ganador` or move out the `errorenTurno` span out side of `ganador`. once the message is displayed there is no longer an element named `errorenTurno`

Answer (score 0):

Add a null check to element before using it:

```
function jugada(evt) { // checks the move
    if(document.getElementById('errorenTurno')!== null )
         document.getElementById('errorenTurno').innerHTML = '';
```

and initialize x variable used in loop using var keyword:

```
function detener(gano) { // deletes the event listener from spans in table
    if (gano == 1) {
        for (var x = 0; x <= 8; x++) {
            document.getElementById('boton' + x).removeEventListener('click', jugada);
        }
    }
}
```

and your html contain not closed tr tag and an extra tr close tag just before html end:

```
 <tr>
     <td><span id="boton6">7</span>
     </td>
     <td><span id="boton7">8</span>
     </td>
     <td><span id="boton8">9</span>
     </td>
  <!-- add here closing tr tag-->
 </tr>
</table>
```

[Here is Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jL4D/)